# Turn off file caching in Aptana 3

Tags: git, caching, aptana, aptana3

Aptana 3 is caching my files and is being a pain. This is my third install of Aptana across different comps and the first time I'm getting this problem.

Example:

I open application.tpl and edit it, followed by a save.
I overwrite via git application.tpl and when I open it, it's my old version, not the new, overwritten one.
I can copy application.tpl to application 2.tpl, open it, edit it, save it.
Delete application.tpl.
Rename application 2.tpl to application.tpl.
Lo and behold, Aptana opens the old version of application.tpl.

This is a huge problem.

Extra info:
I'm not using the git plugin, I'm using the terminal for git. This is the Mac version of Aptana 3 on a Macbook Pro. I also have a windows version on one laptop that doesn't do this and I have another Mac Aptana 3 on on an iMac and it doesn't do this either. I only use git on the Macbook pro so I'm thinking it's possible this is a bug in Aptana maybe releated to not using the git plugin...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of Aptana Studio which uses Eclipse 3.7 platform, in `Preferences-> General -> Workspace` you have `Refresh using native hooks or polling` and `Refresh on Access` options. Make sure both of them are checked.

Comment: Both of those options are already checked. I'm certain this is a bug in the newest version of Aptana. I was having more problems than just this so this morning I installed an old version (3.0.5) and it fixes every problem I was having. Too bad Aptana doesn't have an easy bug reporting system...